# int value changed to zero after popViewController

Tags: iphone, popviewcontrolleranimated

I've two view controllers say **A** & **B**

**In A.h I am doing**

```
{
    int cId;
    bool selected;
}

@property (readwrite) int cId;
```

**In A.m I am doing**

```
@synthesize cId;

- (void) viewWillAppear : (BOOL) animated
{
   //It will only call if its popBacked
   if(selected==YES) //I set it to YES some where in my A.m and its push to : B
   {
      selected=NO;
      NSLog(@"%d",cId); //getting 0 (zero)
   }
}
```

**In B.m I am doing**

```
#import "A.h"

- (void) sentBack : (int) cIdValue
{
    A *obj=[A alloc] init];
    obj.cId=cIdValue;
    NSLog(@"%d",obj.cId); //Its print properly
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

My problem is, when I pop back its value changes and set to 0 (zero). So I can't access my correct cId. Why it is changes? What I am doing wrong? Any help, suggestion is helpful.
**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Edited your code of B.m

```
#import "A.h"

- (void) sentBack : (int) cIdValue {
   if([[self.navigationController viewControllers] count]>0) {                
               A *AViewCont=[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
              AViewCont.cId=cIdValue;
              [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
          }
}
```

Try this one may help you.

Comment: thanks for answer, When I tried your changes, it show me an error like, **Property cId not found on object of type UIViewController**.

Comment: Hemang, Try the above code now will definately solve your problem. I have edited the code little bit.

Comment: thanks its working! :) Can you please tell me, why I was wrong in my above code (In my question)!! It will helpful.

Comment: You were creating the new object of your "A" view controller and that will have another memory slot in the memory. Where as in my code I fetched the original reference(instance) of that controller from NavigationStack and assigned the value in that instance's cId property.

Answer (score 1):

**Why it is changes?** Because the value in cId is still zero.

**What I am doing wrong?**

You are creating a different instance for Class A and assigning the value to its attribute (cId).

In your case, the Class A Instance (lets say A1) from where you pushed Class B is entirely different and has no relation with the Class A instance (lets say A2) you created in sentBack Method. So assigning a value in A2 will not reflect in A1.

**So what you need to do?**

```
- (void) sentBack : (int) cIdValue {
   if([self.navigationController.viewControllers count]> 0) {                
               A *obj =[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:
                             [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]-1];
              obj.cId=cIdValue;
              [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
          }
}
```

Here you accessing A1 (Class A Instance from where you pushed Class B) itself from the Navigation stack, so now A2 (`A *obj`) is pointing to original A1. Now assign `cId` with an `int` value and  pop B you will get the new value assigned to `cId`.